# How to select column names from table by domain name of column in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I need to select column names of certain domain in Firebird.

E.g. there is a domain `COORDINATE` and I want to select all column names with this domain.

Is it possible to do this?

I'm using Firebird 2.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is stored in `rdb$relation_fields`:

```
select rdb$relation_name, 
       rdb$field_name
from rdb$relation_fields
where rdb$field_source = 'COORDINATE';
```